# static variable initalization syncronizes in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, static, initialization

In the following scenario:

```
HeavyInitClass* f()
{
    static HeavyInitClass* heavy = new HeavyInitClass();
    return heavy;
}
```

I know that in C++11 heavy will be initialized exactly once in a multithreaded environment because the flag that marks that heavy was not initialized is thread-safe.

BUT does it also block the threads until heavy has been initialized?
If 100 threads call f() in the same time, does the 99 other threads wait until the initializing thread finishes the initialization?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How else would you do it, considering you have arbitrary initialising and no way to get rid of a partial job?

Comment: isn't `static` redundant in this case ?

Comment: @user2485710 if you don't put `static`, you are going to get a new `HeavyInitClass` pointer every time you call `f()`... the objective here is that `f()` always return the same object. Anyway, I'd use C++11's `unique_ptr<HeavyInitClass>` instead of `HeavyInitClass*` as the return value of `f()` just in case `HeavyInitClass` has to do any cleanup on its destructor...

Comment: @Massa yep, I missed that part, I was simplifying too much.

Comment: @Massa Returning a `unique_ptr` would transfer ownership, which is *not* what you want to do.

Comment: @T.C. you are, of course, right! So, let's pretend I said "anyway, I'd use `shared_ptr<HeavyInitClass>` instead of `HeavyInitClass*`"... :D

Comment: @Massa Not as return value only though, because in that case you run into the risk that the static instance gets deleted early.

Comment: No, a static variable is destroyed only after `main` exits...

Comment: @Massa There's no real reason to return a `shared_ptr`, which is (1) comparatively expensive and (2) unnecessarily constraining. If you want destruction to happen you can simply declare it as `static HeavyInitClass heavy;` and return `&heavy`. The problem there is that if the destructor relies on another static object, or the destructor of another static object relies on this object, you are [dead](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/construct-on-first-use-v2.html).

Comment: @T.C. in this case, I think it would be cleaner to return a reference...

Comment: Either would work; it depends more on what you want the interface of `f()` to be. My point is that you don't need the reference-counting semantics of `shared_ptr` because the object should never be destructed before `main` returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is mandated by §6.7 [stmt.dcl]/p4 of the standard:

> If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.

In other words, yes. The other threads must block until initialization is complete.